# PHP: is it wasteful doing all these checks?

Tags: php

I'am going to write an IF conditional like this:

```
if (isset($_GET['code']) && !empty($_GET['code']) && ctype_digit($_GET['code'])){
   //other code here
}
```

I mean, of course if I only check:

```
if(ctype_digit($_GET['code'])){ }
```

of course $_GET['code'] exists and it is not empty, isn't it wasteful writing this conditional the first way?

Comment: The last one will result in notices when the thing is not set

Comment: Using *both* `isset` and `!empty` is overkill, but you *should* use one of them to make sure that `$_GET['code']` exists before you try to access it.

Comment: You're doing too many things at once. You're checking if a variable exists, then do validate it. In real-world scenario, you need a validation layer for validation tasks, while checking if a variable exists remains the same

Answer (score 3):

It is necessary to check if `$_GET['code']` is set, before you call the function: `ctype_digit()`
In case `$_GET['code']` is not set, you would get an message similar to this:

> Notice: Undefined index: code in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 2

Comment: You should also mention, that he'd get this notice in case he has error_reporting thing turned on

Comment: I have never met someone who turned off **error_reporting**. Maybe you mean **display_errors**, but then you can still see the errors in the logfile.

Comment: You can also use error_reporting=E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE to disable logging notices and therefore you can omit this two checks.

Comment: @arubacao I have seen many times people turn off like `error_reporting(0)` at the top of `index.php` or in similar way. Look around many popular CMS's

Comment: If you have to hide the notices it generates then it is bad code.

Comment: @AbraCadaver yeah that's right. But when working with popular CMS's out there (namely Joomla, Drupal, Wp, Presta Shop, OS Commerce) you somehow must work with crappy code, if you want to earn money quickly :P

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not wasteful to validate your input but it is if you write all that more then once. I would create a method or function called isDigit() and required() and use those to check your input. As a code review note, you should have already validated the required fields in $_GET at the very beginning of the code if you know what is required or not. (Actually I wouldn't even call $_GET directly I would have it handled in an Object that validates and sanitizes data from the outside.)

Answer (score -1):

It depends on your error handling. If you will omit the first check and element with key 'code'  won't exist in `$_GET` array, `E_NOTICE` will be raised. And, for example, if your server responses with 500 error in this cases, user will see a nasty 500 page.
If you error reporting is disabled for E_NOTICE you can omit the fist and the second checks.

Answer (score -2):

using `isset()` and `ctype_digit()` should be fine.